# The direct sum of two finitely generated algebras is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, direct-sum

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets of variables. Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Suppose $S$ and $T$ are finitely generated $R$-algebras. Then $S\cong R[X]/I$ and $T\cong R[Y]/J$ for some $R[X]$-ideal $I$ and $R[Y]$-ideal $J$.

Why is $S\bigoplus T$ a finitely generated $R$-algebra? I wanted to say "just combine the generators of $S$ and $T$" together, but isn't that saying that

$$\frac{R[X]}{I}\oplus\frac{R[Y]}{J}\cong \frac{R[X,Y]}{IR[X,Y]+JR[X,Y]}?$$

But if that's the case, then I'm confused because I thought

$$\frac{R[X]}{I}\otimes\frac{R[Y]}{J}\cong \frac{R[X,Y]}{IR[X,Y]+JR[X,Y]}?$$

But I thought the direct sum and tensor product were very different operations?

Comment: What is $R/I$ or $R/J$ supposed to mean? And what are you tensoring over?

Comment: But $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R[X]$ and $R[Y]$, respectively, not of $R$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re making it much too hard, perhaps by looking at the situation too abstractly.

In my book, $S\oplus T$ is the set of all pairs $(s,t)$ for which $s\in S$, $t\in T$. In other words, as a *set*, $S\oplus T$ is equal to $S\times T$. Addition and multiplication take place coordinatewise, so that the zero-element is $(0,0)$ and the multiplicative identity is $(1,1)$. So if $\{x,\cdots,x_m\}$ is a generating set for the algebra $S$ and $\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$ does the same for $T$, then a generating set for $S\oplus T$ is $\{(x_1,0),\cdots,(x_m,0),(0,y_1),\cdots,(0,y_n)\}$.

That should be good enough, I think.

Comment: I agree! This is how I thought about the problem, but I was getting tripped up on how the isomorphisms went... I guess my question is really one about how should these isomorphisms go, rather than actually showing that $S\oplus T$ is a finitely generated algebra (because it obviously should be). In other words, what I think you're saying is that $S\oplus T\cong R[X,Y]/K$ for some $K$. My question really is, what is this $K$? Is it just $I R[X,Y] + J R[X,Y]$? Thanks!

Comment: Oh my. I’ve burnt my brain out on another question tonight, and I’m completely out of it. But your $K$ would have to take note of the fact that every product $(x_i,0)(0,y_j)$ has to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by $\oplus$ when you are working with $R$-algebras, or more generally with commutative rings? See [this wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_rings).

If you are writing $\oplus$ to mean the coproduct (in the category of $R$-algebras), then you ought to write $\otimes_R$ instead, and your equation is correct. If you mean the product, then you ought to write 
$\times$ instead, and your equation is incorrect (e.g., with $I=J=0$, $\mathbb{C}[X]\times \mathbb{C}[Y]$ is not a domain, so it can't be $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$), but see @Lubin's answer for more in this case. If you mean neither of those, you should clarify what it is that you mean (and your equation is probably incorrect).